# MYSQL Insert a spcific value to a col

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I need to update a DB that has errors within it.

I have created and imported a second table with all the correct fields. This statement compares the two tables for the col that has the error in it returning all is_councilors = Y :

```
 SELECT users_base.first_name, users_base.is_councilor,
      users_base.email,
      users_bk2.is_councilor
    FROM users_base
    INNER JOIN users_bk2
    ON users_base.first_name=users_bk2.first_name AND users_base.email = users_bk2.email 
    WHERE users_bk2.is_councilor = 'Y';
```

My question: what is the insert/update statement to update users_base.is_councilor to a value of '1' WHERE users_bk2.is_councilor is a value of 'Y' now that i'm generating this list?

Comment: That would be an UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
UPDATE users_base ub
    INNER JOIN users_bk2 ub2
    ON ub.first_name=ub2.first_name 
    AND ub.email = ub2.email
SET ub.is_councilor = '1'
WHERE ub2.is_councilor = 'Y'
```